# how to reload an iframe when moving to another iframe on the same page?

Tags: php, html, iframe, reload

I use the psyplay theme in wordpress, by displaying many iframes on a single page.
code I use :[player.php](https://layar21.pro/player-php.txt)

results are displayed :[my site](https://layar21.pro/the-battleship-island/)

and how to reload iframe when I click on another server button ?

I beg for his help, because I am a beginner, 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: yes i am still in the learning phase, do you have a solution?

Comment: I can understand that you're learning, but that doesn't mean you ask for help without trying anything. Show us the code you have done so far.

Comment: I use this function: $("#reload").click(function(){$("#iframe").attr("src", $("#iframe").attr("src"));
});</script>

Comment: this does not work for all iframes, iframe reloads only in frame1

Comment: while the php code I use is: <?php $numerado = 1; { while( have_rows('player') ): the_row(); ?>
<li><div class="les-title">
<i class="fa fa-server mr5"></i>
<strong>Server <?php echo $numerado; ?></strong>
</div>
<div class="les-content"><a href="#tab<?php echo $numerado; ?>"id="reload"><?php  the_sub_field('quality_player'); ?></a></div>
</li>
<?php $numerado++; ?>